# Silverlight ChildWindow.Closed event fires immediately after .Show()

Tags: c#, silverlight

I'm trying to create a ChildWindow in silverlight for a user to enter some data. Whenever I call the `.Show()` function, the `.Closed` event fires immediately. The browser (IE8) then throws this message over and over again:

```
Line: 56
Error: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application 
Code: 2272    
Category: ParserError       
Message: Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key PhoneDisabledBrush     
File:      
Line: 43     
Position: 155
```

If I click this message away about 15 times, it eventually gives me a stack overflow error in IE. I never actually see the ChildWindow get displayed at all before this message comes up, however, it does go through the `.Closed` event before these errors occur.

The child window currently has no code in it, just a few basic silverlight controls added (textblock, textboxes, etc.)

The childwindow is instantiated like this:

```
    public TickerAdminControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        winNewMsg = new windAddNewTickerMessage();
        winNewMsg.Closed += new EventHandler(winNewMsg_Closed);
    }
```

The `.Closed` event looks like this:

```
    void winNewMsg_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (winNewMsg.DialogResult == true)
        {
            TickerProxy.GetAllMessagesAsync();
        }
    }
```

It really couldn't be more basic, so I'm baffled by this error. The `.Show()` is called in a simple button click event on a UserControl.

EDIT: This only occurs on IE. If I use Chrome, it works without changing any code.

2nd EDIT: This appears to only happen when I am running in Debug from Visual Studio. If I pull up the site manually (Http://localhost:3881/Default.aspx) everything works fine, which is why it worked in Chrome. It also works in IE8 when I access it manually. I think I'm even more confused now.

3rd EDIT: While everything appears to work fine when running in non-debug, the errors persist but allow the child window to display an operate properly. In the bottom left I get an "Error" message, and if I click it, it repeats this error 15 times:

```
Message: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.   
at MS.Internal.XcpImports.VisualStateManager_GoToState(Control reference, String StateName, Boolean useTransitions, Boolean& refreshInheritanceContext)
at System.Windows.VisualStateManager.GoToState(Control control, String stateName, Boolean useTransitions)
   at System.Windows.Controls.HyperlinkButton.ChangeVisualState(Boolean useTransitions)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.UpdateStateFlags(Boolean disable)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnIsEnabledChanged(IsEnabledChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Control.OnIsEnabledChanged(Control control, EventArgs args)
   at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName, UInt32 flags)
Line: 1
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost:3881/default.aspx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Turns out I had a set of styled Hyperlink Buttons on the app calling the ChildWindow that were set to look for a Static Resource "PhoneDisabledBrush" that didn't exist. This never came up before because I have never changed them to disabled. Seems a little odd that VS2010 wouldn't through a compile time exception for this, but I just removed the code and it works smoothly.